# Copy documents with default item ID column between document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, copy-item, copy-content

We have a document library with with a few files which we are trying to replicate for the same reason , we want to copy all the files(with metadata) along with the default Item ID column to the new document library.

For Eg.

This is a source document library with the Default ID column , We want to copy the exact same ID column values to the Default ID column in the destination list.

[image]

Read lot of articles online ,Unfortunately there are no articles pertaining to copying the default item ID column.

Would appreciate if anyone could let me know if this could be done using MS Flows

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have created a flow to test.

When copying a file to the new document library, the original file ID will also change.

In fact, it's impossible to keep the original file ID in the new document library.